# How to not overlap any borders on irregular table?

Tags: html, css, border

I am having some styles troubles in bordering an **irregular table** such like this one:
[Irregular tables and overlapped borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrQR3.png)

As you can see, around every td element I got a 1px border style but, when "cornering" with other td's I get **overlapped borders**.

How could I make it look 1px border for every td in this table?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding **border-collapse: collapse** to your table's class.

Alternatively, you could add some space between cells using **border-spacing: 2px**

Comment: **border-collapse: collapse;** fixed my issue. Thank you, aks44, upvote for you!